# Is there a Eclipse tool similar to T4?

Tags: eclipse, code-generation, metaprogramming, t4

Is there a tool in eclipse similar to T4? T4 is mainly used as a code-generation tool but I use T4 to generate all kind of text artifacts.

I am primarily looking to generate C/C++ code.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Around the Eclipse ecosystem the is a huge work on the **[EMF](http://eclipse.org/modeling/emf/)** project:

Inside this umbrella, there are [many tools](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/?project=xpand) for code-gen like

- XPand
- Jet
- Acceleo and more...

If you like something very effective and taking care of separations of concerns avaiable in both Java and .NET world, I would recommend to take a look to [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/).

I already posted some time ago about [template engine selection](http://pjmolina.com/metalevel/2009/06/choosing-a-template-engine-for-code-generation/) and the benefits of StringTemplate over the rest: no side effects.

Comment: I looked at StringTemplate quickly but I was struggling to find some sample templates to look at. In the end I ended up writing a small engine myself (ofc).

Answer (score 1):

I did my part of research on that, when I aimed to get unified code generation regardless of IDE/platform/development OS.

I ended up still choosing T4 for the following reasons:

1. It's very well supported on MSFT/.NET, and core level - not going to go away
2. There is complete and compatible open-source alternative through MonoDevelop
3. When code-generation is separated and recognized, cross-platform IDE support is straightforward

I have developed extensive usage of T4, including any platform code, status tracking and documentation artifacts. The examples also explaining cross-platform IDE usage can be found as well.

http://abstractiondev.wordpress.com/demo-videos/

The video-lists about following topics cover the question at hand, but you might find others interesting as well:

- Getting Started with Visual Studio T4
- Multiplatform Native Development Automation

Comment: That's a good answer, no question about it. But how is it related to the question? You are assuming things, and you shouldn't. You are assuming that you know what the OP wants to achieve, and you don't. Otherwise you would have gotten a +1.

Comment: @JensG I know it's not related, but I focused on what the OP says. He's looking to generate mainly C/C++, but he himself mentions that he himself uses T4 to generate all kinds of artifacts. I didn't assume that much, just recognized the alike pattern that me myself had when I tried to find out if there is alike thing in Eclipse :-)

Comment: I appreciate the answer although I am working in a pretty large organization where Eclipse is one of the supported platforms. I was hoping in finding a tool in that suite that worked out of the box just as T4 does. Have you retained the list of potential T4 candidates?

Comment: There seems to be something called JET for Eclipse.

Comment: @FuleSnabel Sorry, I don't have the list (anymore). All I recall was, that at the time I did't identify anything as-native-as-T4-on-.NET comparable. Thus: if the solution anyway requires "command-line-execution" and "plugging with Eclipse workflow", the T4 (that's practically available with Mono Runtime + MonoDevelop distribution) becomes as-viable-option as anything.